# How to change from a 'tilted' list back to original

Tags: python, list, wordsearch

I have this piece of code that turns the list 'Puzzle' from its original format of this:

```
Puzzle = ["FUNCTIONRRIRAI",
          "RAIOONFRCCPWON",
          "PTCSNOBEUITOLO",
          "BNCACIANTOSLIH",
          "RBYOLILYNREFBT",
          "HYYNOGESTIBRIY",
          "AATTSIONCMCENP",
          "UORTENRRCBFVAU",
          "CEBEECVWIERORI",
          "PROCESSORTOPYF",
          "OHCOMPUTERHSOS",
          "YCYPRESREOSMRW",
          "OATHBRMVTHHCTR",
          "PGORWOOUIPSCHP"]
```

into this:

```
F
RU
PAN
BTIC
RNCOT
HBCSOI
AYYANNO
UAYOCOFN
COTNLIBRR
PERTOIAECR
ORBTSGLNUCI
YHOEEIEYTIPR
OCCCENOSNOTWA
PAYOECRNTRSOOI
GTPMSVRCIELLN
OHRPSWCMBFIO
RBEUOIBCRBH
WRSTREFEIT
OMRETRVNY
OVEROOAP
UTOHPRU
IHSSYI
PHMOF
SCRS
CTW
HR
P
```

I need a way to be able to change the Puzzle back to its original format once i have made the modifications i need. 
Here is the code for rotating the puzzle:

```
i = 0
        while i < len(Puzzle) * 2:
            character = ""
            for y in range(0, len(Puzzle)):
                for x in range(0, len(Puzzle[0])):
                    if (y - x) + i == 13:
                        character += Puzzle[x][y]
            if character != "":
                LeftOutPuz.append(character)
            i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for the example you've provided

```py
original = ["FUNCTIONRRIRAI",
            "RAIOONFRCCPWON",
            "PTCSNOBEUITOLO",
            "BNCACIANTOSLIH",
            "RBYOLILYNREFBT",
            "HYYNOGESTIBRIY",
            "AATTSIONCMCENP",
            "UORTENRRCBFVAU",
            "CEBEECVWIERORI",
            "PROCESSORTOPYF",
            "OHCOMPUTERHSOS",
            "YCYPRESREOSMRW",
            "OATHBRMVTHHCTR",
            "PGORWOOUIPSCHP"]

puzzle = ['F',
          'RU',
          'PAN',
          'BTIC',
          'RNCOT',
          'HBCSOI',
          'AYYANNO',
          'UAYOCOFN',
          'COTNLIBRR',
          'PERTOIAECR',
          'ORBTSGLNUCI',
          'YHOEEIEYTIPR',
          'OCCCENOSNOTWA',
          'PAYOECRNTRSOOI',
          'GTPMSVRCIELLN',
          'OHRPSWCMBFIO',
          'RBEUOIBCRBH',
          'WRSTREFEIT',
          'OMRETRVNY',
          'OVEROOAP',
          'UTOHPRU',
          'IHSSYI',
          'PHMOF',
          'SCRS',
          'CTW',
          'HR',
          'P']

max_lines = 14
solution = [''] * max_lines

decrement = 0
lineno = -1
for item in puzzle:
    lineno += 1
    index = lineno
    if lineno >= max_lines:
        index = max_lines - 1
    decrement = 0
    for char in item:
        solution[index - decrement] += char
        decrement += 1

assert(solution == original)
```

**Note**: The above code uses string concatenation, which is inherently slow, if performance is an issue, use [bytearray](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bytearray) instead.

My algorithm is essentially a reversed version of the algorithm used to generate the puzzle. This is how it works, if you're interested->

*I refer to the `puzzle` list indexes as `line number`(s)*

- Iterate through the list, and the strings within the list, whenever an item in the list is exhausted, line number is incremented
- The **very first character** of each item, should be in the *same index* as the line number (starting from 0).

  For example, in line 2 (actually 1, when starting from 0), the 1st character is `R`, this should be in the `1st` index (starting from 0) of our list
- The **second character**, will be in the *previous index*

  For example, in line 2 (actually 1, when starting from 0), the 2nd character is `U`, this should be in the `0th` index of our list
- For the next character, we'll once again have to *step down one index* and so on...
- Do this until line number is **greater than or equal** to the *length of `original` list* (alternatively, the length of the longest item in `puzzle` list), in this case `14`
- Once `line no >= 14`, `index` is no longer incremented and should stay at the max index, which is 13 in this case. Everything else will stay the same.

In the end, you should have the original list

Edited to match OP's exact needs.

Comment: How would I edit this so a text file isnt needed and just takes the input of Puzzle = ["F", "RU","PAN"...]

Comment: @charlies Check the answer again